How can i calculate the average of a custom event value on GA4?
i have login time for multiple users and i want to show the average, min and max of the login time. how can i do that on GA4 ? following is my code:
gtag('event', 'login_time', {
    event_category: 'timing',
    event_label: 'Time to login',
    value: Math.round(timeToLogin) // Time in milliseconds
  })

i am able to get the login time on GA4 but it shows me the sum of all values. how can i get the average instead


It's not related to your GTAG code. Freeform doesn't support choosing a calculation method like Lookerstudio does, and it defaults to using the sum instead of the average for event value.
To address this, you can create new calculated metrics in custom definitions that calculate the average of event_values and use them instead of the built-in event_value.

Add "Event count" as metric to the report too, so you can calculate the average like this:
Avg Event value = Event value / Event count

